# How to send a value using button from view to controller in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to pass a value from view to controller using a button as such i want to access an if condition using that value passed from button in order to redirect the flow of function.

Button view:

```
 <button type="button" name = 'draft' value = 'draft' 
onclick="location.href='<?php echo 
site_url().'/invoice_invoice/create_invoice/';?>'" class="btn btn-circle 
grey-salsa btn-outline">Cancel</button>
```

controller :
In the controller i want to keep an if loop which checks whether value of the button that is 'draft' is posted or not in the controller

Comment: Please post some of code you expected passing value to controller using a button.

Answer (score 2):

You can passed value like this:

```
location.href='<?php echo site_url().'/invoice_invoice/create_invoice/'.$value;?>'
```

and access it in controller like this

```
function create_invoice($value){
}
```

or you can used the $_GET

```
location.href='<?php echo site_url().'/invoice_invoice/create_invoice?value='.$value;?>'
```

and access in controller like this

```
function create_invoice(){
   $value = $this->input->get('value');
}
```

or if you have to save form or something then you can used the ajax for this.